# Using gwt-jackson without maven

Tags: gwt, jackson

I would like to use gwt-jackson in the client side in my GWT project without Maven.
Which jars do I need from which urls exactly?

I tried the following without success:

1. I downloaded
   http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/github/nmorel/gwtjackson/gwt-jackson/0.6.2/gwt-jackson-0.6.2.jar
   and added to my buid path.
2. I added `<inherits
   name='com.github.nmorel.gwtjackson.GwtJackson'/>` to my module
   gwt.xml.
3. I tried to run to Quick Start example in
   https://github.com/nmorel/gwt-jackson.
4. Eclipse says "JsonCreator
   cannot be resolved to a type" at compile-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to download the transitive dependencies.

Besides of GWT `gwt-jackson-0.6.2` depends on [jackson-annotations-2.3.3](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.3.3/jackson-annotations-2.3.3.jar) and [jackson-annotations-2.3.3-sources](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.3.3/jackson-annotations-2.3.3-sources.jar).